# Google Sheets Chart: Does Not Resize From Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I am trying to resize a chart in the script. When I run my test function ResizeChart(), it does not resize on the sheet. However, when I run GetChartPosition(), it shows the resized values. It's as though the chart was not "re-drawn" in the GUI.

```
function ResizeChart(){
  var defaultW = 600;
  var defaultH = 378;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Chart Data");
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('width', defaultW)
    .setOption('height', defaultH)
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);  
}
function GetChartPosition(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shData = ss.getSheetByName("Chart Data");
  var shUser = ss.getSheetByName("Charts");

  var charts = shData.getCharts();
  for(i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    Logger.log("Chart ID: %s\r\nAnchor Column: %s\r\nAnchor Row: %s\r\nOffset X: %s\r\nOffset Y: %s\r\nWidth: %s\r\nHeight: %s\r\n",
               charts[i].getChartId(),
               charts[i].getContainerInfo().getAnchorColumn(),
               charts[i].getContainerInfo().getAnchorRow(),
               charts[i].getContainerInfo().getOffsetX(),
               charts[i].getContainerInfo().getOffsetY(),
               charts[i].getOptions().get("width"),
               charts[i].getOptions().get("height")
               );
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong?  MTIA

Comment: This code seems to work for me - you don't happen to have multiple charts in the `Chart Data` sheet do you?

Comment: Yes, I have two. I've tried resizing each of them, no errors reported, and GetChartPosition confirms the new position. To test, I change the defaultW vals, and sure enough, GetChartPosition again confirms the new position...

Comment: Hmmm... why am I only getting email notifications of comments some 3 hrs later?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why my code was not working, as today it is!

I've made no changes to the code, kept testing it, and when I tried today - it just worked as expected.

Oh well, problem "fixed" I guess.